# Do damage boosts stack?

Tags: devil-survivor-2

If I equipped both electric boost(1.2x) and electric amp(1.5x) on a character, how do those passives combine?  Which of the following is it?

- Multiplicative: 1.2*1.5 = 1.8x damage
- Additive: 1.2+1.5 = 2.7x damage
- Highest wins: 1.5x damage
- First equipped wins: 1.2x damage

Comment: From my experience, it seems to depend on the skill. Passives like amps and boosts should be additive. The Auto and Race Skills like Magic Yin, Blitzkrieg, Awakening, and Enlightenment are multiplicative and calculated after amps and boosts. More experiments probably need to be done to confirm/disprove this theory.